# Prevent a specific UPDATE in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, constraints, mysql-workbench

I have this column in my table:

```
  `Status` VARCHAR(5) NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'DRAFT, SENT, or TRASH\nSENT cannot update to DRAFT\n' ,
    CONSTRAINT chk_Status CHECK (`Status` IN ('SENT', 'DRAFT', 'TRASH', NULL))
```

What I want to do is prevent a row with the `Status` of 'SENT' being updated to a `Status` of 'DRAFT'.

EDIT: This is the trigger that I have come up with, but syntactically it doesn't seem to be correct. Any suggestions?

```
TRIGGER update_Status
  BEFORE UPDATE ON `Status` WHERE `Status` = 'SENT'
  ON `EMAIL` FOR EACH ROW
  DENY UPDATE ON `Status` TO 'DRAFT',
```

Comment: You may need something like an `UPDATE` [TRIGGER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DELIMITER /
CREATE TRIGGER update_status
BEFORE UPDATE ON Status 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE wrong_status CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '45123';
  IF new.status = 'DRAFT' AND old.Status = 'SENT' Then
     SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45123'
     SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Status cannot be changed from SENT to DRAFT';
  END IF;
END;
/
DELIMITER ;
```